# Does Apple scan iCloud e-mail like Google does with Gmail?

Tags: icloud, email, gmail

Does anyone know if Apple scans e-mail for marketing purposes like Google does with Gmail?

Or maybe the iCloud e-mail encrypted all the way from client to server/database such that Apple couldn't even read it?

Comment: I don't think they scan it for ad words like google does; iAds are banners that show up in apps, not in email.

Answer (score 1):

With MobileMe, Apple did filter (and block) email:
http://www.cultofmac.com/103703/apple-may-be-invisibly-filtering-your-outgoing-mobileme-email-exclusive/
However, I tried the test mentioned in the article using iCloud email, and the email went through just fine.

EDIT:
Turns out they do, just not in the same way.
http://www.cultofmac.com/217557/apples-deleting-icloud-emails-that-contain-the-phrase-barely-legal-teens/